# Accordion class not removing correctly with javascript when object is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

Not the best with javascript and I'm currently stuck on something. I've managed to put an accordion together that expands and collapses with an :after icon that transforms when the object is opened. It also only allows for one accordion to be open at a time which is what is needed.

My issue is that the :after icon is not functioning correctly because once the "active" class is added, it only gets removed if another object is opened, not if the same object is closed. Does anyone have a solution that could fix this? I need the class to be removed if another accordion is opened, as well as if the object is clicked again to close it.

As mentioned above I'm not the best with JS and i've really only achieved what I have with this accordion from other answers I've found on here. Here is my current code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Javascript

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
if (panel.style.maxHeight){
  panel.style.maxHeight = null;
} else {
  let active = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-div .accordion.active");
  for(let j = 0; j < active.length; j++){
    active[j].classList.remove("active");
    active[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
  }
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
}
});
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="accordion-div">
<h5 class="accordion">Heading</h5>
<div class="panel">
<p>Some Text</p>
<h5 class="accordion">Heading 2</h5>
<div class="panel">
<p>Some Text</p>
<h5 class="accordion">Heading 3</h5>
<div class="panel">
<p>Some Text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
h5.accordion {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 25px!important;
  padding-left:2px!important;
  width: 100%;
  line-height:13px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size:13px!important;
  vertical-align:center;
  font-family:"Avenir Next", sans-serif;
  font-weight:300;
  margin:0;
  margin-top:2px;
  border-bottom:0!important;
}

h5.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  line-height:13px;
  font-size:22px;
  float: right;
  color:#5f5f5f;
  margin-left: 5px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform-origin: 50% 60%;
}

.active:after {
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 2px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  border-bottom:solid 1px #f1f1f1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo that you were not closing div for your headings in your HTML please check the snippet, Also to `open` and `close`, I have added a line of `JS` to first remove the `active` class if present and then toggle based on `this`

Please run the snippet and see

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
this.classList.remove("active");
var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
if (panel.style.maxHeight){
  panel.style.maxHeight = null;
} else {
  let active = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-div .accordion.active");
  for(let j = 0; j < active.length; j++){
    active[j].classList.remove("active");
    active[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
  }
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
}
});
}
```

```css
h5.accordion {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 25px!important;
  padding-left:2px!important;
  width: 100%;
  line-height:13px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size:13px!important;
  vertical-align:center;
  font-family:"Avenir Next", sans-serif;
  font-weight:300;
  margin:0;
  margin-top:2px;
  border-bottom:0!important;
}

h5.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  line-height:13px;
  font-size:22px;
  float: right;
  color:#5f5f5f;
  margin-left: 5px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform-origin: 50% 60%;
}

.active:after {
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 2px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  border-bottom:solid 1px #f1f1f1;
}
javascript
jquery
```

```html
<div class="accordion-div">
<h5 class="accordion">Heading</h5>
<div class="panel">
<p>Some Text</p>
</div>
<h5 class="accordion">Heading 2</h5>
<div class="panel">
<p>Some Text</p>
</div>
<h5 class="accordion">Heading 3</h5>
<div class="panel">
<p>Some Text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Please upvote, Thanks @nckosy.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot yet. Stack overflow has decided my opinion does not matter until 15 other people believe it does. I do appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 0):

First, **remove all** active classes when the `h5` tag is clicked

```js
const removeActiveClasses = (e) => {
    const target = e.targrt || e.currentTarget;
    const active = target.querySelector(".accordion.active");
    active.classList.remove("active");
}
```

Then you need to activate the current element

```js
const activeElement = (e) => {
    const target = e.target.nextElementSibling;
    target.classList.add("active");
}
```

At the End

```
const accordion = e => {
    removeActiveClasses(e);
    activeElement(e);
}

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", accordion);
}
```

**Notice: You do not need to use a loop `because` you only want one active element**